# What size nut for a B7 1-1/8" threaded rod?

Tags: bolts

I have a threaded Rod B7 Alloy Steel 1-1/8-7. What size nut will fit this? I got some nuts size being 1-1/8"-7 but they don't fit.

Comment: What do you mean by "don't fit"?  Any chance you have a thread gage?  If there is any shop wear on the threads, it wouldn't surprise me if the nuts would refuse to spin on finger-tight.  It's a big nut.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I couldn't get them to spin on. I don't have a thread guage.  The threads look clean.

Comment: Has to be one of three things.  Damaged threads, wrong size of nut or rod, or one is a left handed thread.  1 1/8-7 nut should fit on 1 1/8-7 thread.

Comment: Found out the rod was actually 1-1/4"-7. Supplier sent me the wrong one.